# Why have Psam 135 instead of 146 and omit Psalm 147 in Pesukei D'Zimra?

Tags: prayer-book, pesukei-dezimra, saadya-gaon

In all *siddurim* I know of—and *halachic* compendia that I've seen—*pesukei d'zimra* contains, among other things, psalms 145–150. However, in the *siddur* of Rav Sa'adia Gaon, he replaces Psalm 146 by 135 and omits Psalm 147. This can be seen [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=92) (lines 16ff); although there is one manuscript that includes Psalm 146 and 147, the rest don't.

Is there anywhere else that this is discussed? I'd be interested in (a) other omissions of Psalm 147 in this context, whether or not they mention Rav Sa'adia Gaon, and (b) discussions of Rav Sa'adia Gaon's divergence, whether from traditional or academic sources.

Comment: Are you aware of the Rashi-Meiri debate regarding pesukei dezimra?

Comment: (1) Actually, although it is mentioned in the variant text, Psalm 146 isn't mentioned in the main text either. Instead [Psalm 135](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26d5.htm)[:3] is given (see note for line 16, on the left side). (2) The note for line 22 (on the left side) brings that he only mentions 5 Psalms, whereas [Masekhet Soferim 17:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.17.11?lang=bi&lang2=en) says there are 6.

Comment: The Chabad.org commentary on [Mishneh Torah, Tefilah and Birkat Kohanim 7:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920169/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Seven.htm#v12) s.v. "until the end of the Book [of Psalms]"says "_The Rambam understands פסוקי דזמרא as referring to the last six chapters of Psalms (Kessef Mishneh). This definition is also accepted by Rav Yitzchok Alfasi and Rabbenu Asher_". This suggests there might exist other listings of the Psalms of _pesukei d'zimra_ that were not accepted.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesukei_dezimra#Origin

Comment: @TamirEvan Thanks I missed 135; see the edit. I saw the note, but they don't explain why.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I wasn't until now. Explaining that would probably answer this question. Note that Rashi still said more than 148 and 150, so his comment in Shabbat might be more of his opinion on the history of PDZ rather than his suggested contents.